# Loops in a binary iterated function system

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary, iterated-function-system

Take a function $f(x)$ which operates on numbers written in binary. It is a three step operation:

1. Split the number into digits in even- and odd-numbered places. (For example, the number $\underline{1}1\underline{0}1\underline{0}$ becomes $[\underline{100},11]$. Underlines added for clarity.)
2. Concatenate the two sets of digits together, with the set containing the original first digit first. ($10011$)
3. Add one to this new binary number. ($10100$)

There are some numbers such that $f(x)=x$ ($10010$ for example). However, the sequence $a_0 = 1, a_{n+1} = f(a_{n})$, seems to remarkably miss all of them. I'm trying to prove that the sequence divereges, i.e. does not loop at any point. I don't know if this is the case, but I am confident.

I've checked the first million or so terms with a simple python program, which yeilds no counterexamples, however, that is far from a proof. I thought of doing induction on the numbers of the form $2^n$ (Since the function can never decrease the digit count, and only increases by 1, $2^n-1$ and $2^n$ are always part of the sequence (at least up to the point of a hypothetical repeat). If I can prove that $f(f(f(...f(2^n))...)))=2^{n+1}$, then that is enough to show there are no loops, however, I couldn't manage to. How can I prove this sequence divereges?

Comment: I get a loop even on the actual example given in your question: `11010 --> 10100 --> 11001 --> 10111 --> 11110 --> 11100 --> 11011 --> 11000 --> 10011 --> 10110 --> 11010`

Comment: BTW, an interesting observation is that $f(x) = x$ for every $x$ of the form $4^n+2$ (with $n\in\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb that's the odd thing, there seems to be a lot of loops but somehow building from one seems to avoid them

Comment: Well, I showed you a loop in the first comment, using the same starting value that you've used in your question. So in light of this counterexample, I cannot quite see how your conjecture of the sequence diverging for every starting value can be correct.

Comment: the statement wasn't every starting value, simply that starting at 1 diverges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I scratch the proof as follows:

1. Given two numbers $a$ and $b$, $a\neq b \rightarrow f(a) \neq f(b)$ and vice versa.
2. Most of the time, $f(x)$ won't change the number of digits in binary form. So we have the following: considering the domain $A=[2^n-1,2^{n+1}-1]$, $f$ maps $A$ to domain $A'=[2^n,2^{n+1}]$.

This can be seen from $f(2^n-1)=2^n$. After that, the digit of the number in binary form won't decrease to n. And only one number in domain $A$ would give $2^{n+1}$, which is $2^{n+1}-1$. The other number in domain $A$ can only be mapped to a number within such range since the number of digits is fixed.

3. Considering our first statement, $f: A\rightarrow A'$ is a bijection mapping.
4. $f:\mathbf{N} \rightarrow \mathbf{N}^+$ is also a bijection mapping.

Consider the bijection mapping from $A$ to $A'$. There are $2^n+2$ distinct numbers($2^n-1$ to $2^{n+1}$). If we call $f(a)=b$ forms a directed link between $a$ and $b$, then there are $2^n+1$ directed links(the size of the domain), and it forms a graph $G$.

Consider the first statement, if we have a substructure of $G$: $a\rightarrow b \rightarrow c \rightarrow \ldots$, then it will never end on $b$ since no two numbers map to the same one. Then we can have:

5. $G$ is a vertex-disjoint union of one tree and loops.

A tree with $n$ nodes has $n-1$ links, and a loop with $n$ nodes have $n$ links(e.g., $[18\rightarrow 18]$, 1 node with 1 link point to self).

6. The structure $\ldots \rightarrow (2^n-1) \rightarrow 2^n \rightarrow \ldots $ is not a loop. So does $\ldots \rightarrow 2^{n+1}-1 \rightarrow 2^{n+1} \rightarrow \ldots$. Here we can conclude the sequence $a_0=1$ would never loop, and it will go through the set $\{1,2,4,8,\ldots\}$.

You can test the following statement:

7. All loops are within the domain $A$ for some $n$.

e.g., $n=4$. The structure is following:

$15 \rightarrow 16 \rightarrow 17 \rightarrow 21 \rightarrow 29 \rightarrow 31 \rightarrow 32 $

$18 \rightarrow 18$

$19 \rightarrow 22 \rightarrow 26 \rightarrow 20 \rightarrow 25 \rightarrow 23 \rightarrow 30 \rightarrow 28 \rightarrow 27 \rightarrow 24 \rightarrow 19$

The following is the old answer.

If $\underbrace{f(f(\ldots(f(x))))}_n= f^{n}(x)=x$, we say $x$ is a periodic point with period $n$.

It's easy to see the function f(x) has a period of 3, e.g.:

$[1579046, 1116710, 1312822, 1579046]$

And there are many other points with period 3. These period-3 points indicate there exists a period point for any period $n\in \mathbf{N^+}$. You can refer to Sharkovskii's theorem for detail.

Although there is a period point with an infinite large period, this is not easy to find. I checked your statement to $2^{30}=1073741824$, and it still holds.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question, but thanks for the link to Sharkovskii's Theorem (not sure if it works as my f(x) isn't continuous). It's interesting that all these loops exist but they aren't reachable from the starting point of 1

Comment: I used to like to leave a comment, yet the forum didn't allow newcomers to do such things. So I post an answer at the end.
You can make a linear interpolate at the point where the f(x) doesn't define, which produces a continuous version of f(x), then the theorem applies.

Comment: Hi, @Elliott Price. Please take a look at the new answer. I think it solves the question now.

Comment: thank you so much, that's incredibly simple and elegant

Comment: I guess a high level and less rigorous version of this proof would be: The function is bijective, and the digit count can only increase, therefore powers of 2 and powers of 2 minus one can't be part of loops. 1 is a power of 2 (and a power of 2 minus one), therefore it doesn't loop.

Comment: Yeah, it's a concise version of the proof. ; )